# How to refresh kendo Graph using SignalR notfication

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, kendo-asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I want to refresh kendo graph once I am getting notification from SignalR.
Here is my code

```
function CreateChart()
{

    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            position: "bottom",
            text: "Import Log"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: ""
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                background: "transparent",
                template: "#= dataItem.CategoryField #: \n #= dataItem.Percentage#%"
            }
        },
        dataSource: [{ "CategoryField": "Success", "Percentage": 0 }, { "CategoryField": "Error", "Percentage": 0 }, { "CategoryField": "Info", "Percentage": 0 }, { "CategoryField": "Total", "Percentage": 100}],

        series: [{
            type: "donut",
            field: "Percentage",
            categoryField: "CategoryField"

        }],
        seriesColors: ["Green", "red", "#FFD54C", "#EEEEEE"]

    });
}

updateProgress = function (successPct, errPct, infoPct)
{

    var selectedChart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    var ds = selectedChart.dataSource;

    var progress = ds.at(0);
    var error = ds.at(1);
    var info = ds.at(2);
    var total = ds.at(3);

    progress.set("Percentage", data.SuccessPercentage);
    error.set("Percentage", data.ErrorPercentage);
    info.set("Percentage", data.InfoPercentage);
    total.set("Percentage", 100 - data.SuccessPercentage - data.ErrorPercentage - data.InfoPercentage);

    selectedChart.refresh();


}

  $(document).ready(function () {
      CreateChart();

    var importNotifier = $.connection.runImport;
    importNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (data) {
        $("#chart").append(data.SuccessPercentage + " " +  data.ErrorPercentage + " " + data.InfoPercentage)
        updateProgress(data.SuccessPercentage, data.ErrorPercentage, data.InfoPercentage);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        importNotifier.server.import();
    });
});
```

Here I created method Update Progress to update chart. But chart is not refreshed until entire server side processing is completed. Once All server side processing is completed then only chart update works. I want to update my chart only when I get any notification from SignalR.

Comment: kendo's datasource has a type [signalR](http://developer.telerik.com/products/realtime-data-with-signalr-and-websockets/), have you tried that?

Comment: No.. But I checked code. I think it will not work.Can you please give me some good links if you have

Comment: [link](http://eswkchartdemo.azurewebsites.net/Dataviz/RealtimeDonutChart). I want something like this. But it is not working in my case

Comment: Why do you think the signalR datasource won't work?